# What does SCM mean in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have an option (a plugin?) called "Poll SCM" in Jenkins and I know what it does and how to use it. Please tell me what "SCM" stands for. Is it "Source Code Management", "Sync Code [something]"?

Thanks.

Comment: Software configuration management. But for most of us that effectively means source code management.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I was searching for it for hours.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

SCM = Source Control Management

From [jenkin's tutorial](https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/building-a-node-js-and-react-app-with-npm/#fork-and-clone-the-sample-repository-on-github)

**Section:** *Create your Pipeline project in Jenkins*

**Step 6:** *From the Definition field, choose the Pipeline script from SCM option. This option instructs Jenkins to obtain your Pipeline from **Source Control Management (SCM)**, which will be your locally cloned Git repository.*

Comment: So then if a pull request was merged to master in git, if that triggered a build in Jenkins that it would be considered "Started by an SCM change"?

Answer (score 8):

SCM in Software engineering stands for `Software Configuration Management`, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management) for more details.

It also stands for `Source Control Management` in some Continuous Integration tools like `Jenkins`, please see the accepted answer.